# Hls.js record file

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, hls.js

Hello and thanks for reading,

I have a Hls stream with an m3u8 playlist.
The Video is playing just fine on an Html page with a Video element and https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js

But if I download the segments to join them they are only white pixels. VLC and FFmpeg can't handle them. VLC shows a white pixel for 10seconds and FFmpeg says that there's no stream in the file.

So now I want to know what this hls.js is doing to make it running. To me a non-js developer it all looks a bit confusing. I was able to understand stuff like which function is called when a new segment is loaded. Unfortunately, I was unable to understand stuff about the data. The one character variables are confusing to me.

For now, I capture the stream of the video element and download it later but I don't like this solution at all.

**How to help me**

> It would be very nice if anyone can tell me how to hook into the
> script and tell it to download directly to the disk so I'm independent
> of framerate drops.
>
> If anyone can tell how the script is able to convert the data so that
> the  element can use it and I would be able to implement or do
> it with FFmpeg would be really helpful.
>
> I also thought it might be possible to have a listener when the blob
> changes to store its contents.

Thanks for everyone helping. I'm trying to find a solution for too many hours now.

Answer (score 7):

I found the solution. After looking at their great event system
https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/
and this issue which I contributed too and not just copied
https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/issues/1322

```
var arrayRecord = [];

function download(data, filename) {
    console.log('downloading...');
    var blob = new Blob([arrayConcat(data)], {
        type: 'application/octet-stream'
    });
    saveAs(blob, filename);
}

function arrayConcat(inputArray) {
    var totalLength = inputArray.reduce(function (prev, cur) {
        return prev + cur.length
    }, 0);
    var result = new Uint8Array(totalLength);
    var offset = 0;
    inputArray.forEach(function (element) {
        result.set(element, offset);
        offset += element.length;
    });
    return result;
}

function saveAs(blob, filename) {
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.style = "display: none";
    a.href = url;
    a.download = filename;
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}

function stopRecord() {
    arrayRecord.forEach(function (item) {
        download(item.data['video'], "video.mp4");
        download(item.data['audio'], "audio.mp4");
        item.hls.destroy();
        return false;
    });
}

function startRecord() {
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    var dataStream = {
        'video': [],
        'audio': []
    };
    var hls = new Hls();
    hls.loadSource("Your playlist");
    hls.attachMedia(video);
    hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED, function () {
        video.play();
        hls.on(Hls.Events.BUFFER_APPENDING, function (event, data) {
            console.log("apending");
            dataStream[data.type].push(data.data);
        });
    });
    arrayRecord.push({
        hls: hls,
        data: dataStream
    });
    video.onended = function (e) {
        stopRecord()
    }

}
```